# How to remove corner radius from TextInput in spark

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex-spark

I'm creating a mobile app in `Flex` and `AS3` and the design i recieved has no corner radius in `TextInput` fields.

In mobile projects in `Flash Builder` only `Spark` can be used for layout, and according to the documentation of Adobe the `TextInput` element has no attribute to set the corner radius.

Is there an other way for me to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Look like you'll have to create a custom skin.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i have found an standard skin of spark that gave me the result i wanted.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question so that other people with the same question can find your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your responses, i found and standard skin of `Spark` that has no rounded corners.
This what was the skin i needed to get the result i wanted.

The skin that i found is located in `spark.skins.spark.TextInputSkin`, i leaves everything the same excepts that it has normal corners instead of rounded.

Again thanks for your help.